# android app Free Live Tv suspended from google play

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

App suspended for-Violation of the intellectual property and impersonation or deceptive behavior provisions of the Content Policy. Please refer to the IP infringement and impersonation policy help article for more information.
I don't know particularly where the problem is.
It's the contents or the store listing things.

Please help me out.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about google policies

Comment: because you are distributing copyrighted content without the content provider approval. seems pretty clear to me

Comment: So there's nothing to be copyrighted. I just want to know to which part was creating problem. cause I created my own icon and screenshots are taken from my phone. title "live tv 3g hd". and theres no copyright material only cause i have given links of different websites.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Android Developers,

Your are using others website links in your app. By Google policy terms & conditions Should not use other personal sites. I think this is the mistake you done.